# How to create a directory tree with bash's bracket expansion syntax

Tags: go, filesystems

While `os.MkdirAll` behaves similar to `mkdir -p` creating parents if needed then how would you take input string e.g. `data/{P1/{10..19},P2/{20..29},P3/{30..39}}` and create directory tree?

Answer (score 2):

This string `data/{P1/{10..19},P2/{20..29},P3/{30..39}}` is a [bash brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

There are some libraries that have implemented this:

- https://github.com/thomasheller/braceexpansion
- https://github.com/kujtimiihoxha/go-brace-expansion

You can also use filepath.Glob for something similar to the bash wildcard syntax: https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob

Alternatively you could shell out to bash:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "echo data/{P1/{10..19},P2/{20..29},P3/{30..39}}")
respBytes, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

for _, path := range strings.Fields(string(respBytes)) {
    os.MkdirAll(path, 0700)
}
```

Worth noting that if there are spaces in the folder/filenames this strategy will not work.

Comment: From your answer then: `
for _, path := range strings.Fields(string(respBytes)) {os.MkdirAll(path, 0700)}`

Comment: @mkungla thanks, added it to my example. Please accept the answer if it answers your question :)